# How to overwrite a homepage automatically at a given time?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm designing a site that has a sale every 24 hours and directly at midnight that sale ends and a new one starts. I need to update the product images, the add to cart buttons, the product info, so much that it would be almost impossible to update everything at an exact point. This also happens every night, so doing this manually at midnight every night would be very grueling.

I need a way to make up the homepage beforehand, then update the  the homepage automatically at midnight using the servers clock. I was thinking maybe some script to overwrite the html at a given time maybe using FTP or something. Just can't figure it out or find it anywhere.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: use a cron job on the server. cron can schedule anything to run at specified times/intervals down to 1 minute granularity.

Comment: Use PHP or another server-side language to generate your content dynamically rather than static HTML.

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to create a table .. 'sales' - add columns that represent your sale specific items - at the top of the sale.php page - you query today's sale (based on date field) and populate the sale.php html template with that data.

Comment: ultimately, you'll need to create a system where you can schedule pages to show at specific times. But if you need something quick, the solution by @Emissary works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ***really*** primitive but if you insist on creating static *HTML* pages and simply want to swap them out at a set time you could do something similar to the following:

```php
<?php //index.php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');    
if(time() > strtotime('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00')) 
    include './new-page.html';
else 
    include './old-page.html';
```

you may find the [*PHP* timezone docs](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) useful.

Comment: this works, had to do this at one of my old workplace... I was shaking my head the whole time, but it works...

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need, since I have a mass of information on the entire page to update, instead of just on spot on the page. Thank you so much!